# Как настроить страницу поиска wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Всем привет! Вот такой вопросик, думаю для понимающих сразу станет ясно что я пошел по неправильному пути и начал писать тему с нуля и, естественно, где то напортачил, только не могу понять где))) Проблема такова: создал шаблон страницы search.php засунул прекрасный код ( видимо не до конца прекрасный))) ) , подвязал с плагином для поиска Relevanssi, и вроде бы все отлично, но дело в том, что если по результату ничего не найдено, то сообщение что ничего не найдено выводится, но пропадает половина хедера и футер. Может есть у кого мысли где я дурак? Код залил сюда: pastebin.com/bfiyLJfF

Comment: если отключить плагин для поиска, результат не меняется?

Comment: отключил, но теперь при попытке что то найти выводится шаблон главной страницы и ничего не ищется, а если так же написать несуществующий запрос, то я заметил что пропадают данные в тех местах, где я указал выводить посты, какие мне нужно, вот они все пустые, дивы только есть, а все что дальше отсутствует.

Comment: шаблон главной выводится при обращении к странице вида `http://адрес_сайта/?s=фраза_для_поиска`?

Comment: да, все так и есть.